# How to join tables in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have three tables that want to join them together. first table is questions, second is sections and third is options.
I want to fetch all records of table questions where formid for example is 120 and all records of table sections where it's questionid is equal to questionid of fetched questions table questionid.
And all record of third table 'options' where options.questionid=questions.questionid.

```
    $questions=DB::table('sections')
            ->rightJoin('questions',function($join ){
                $join->on('questions.questionid','=','sections.questionid');
            })
            ->leftJoin('options',function($join ){
                $join->on('questions.questionid','=','options.questionid');
            })
            ->where('questions.formid',$formId)
            ->get();
```

This code return null for questionid where no matched in sections table.
How to solve this issue?

Comment: Well, what would you like your search to return for unmatched questions?

Comment: the questionid of questions table where('questions.formid',$formId) @Shadow

Comment: In DB::table() you should use questions and then make joins with it.

Answer (score 0):

Try it.

```
$questions=DB::table('questions')
        ->join('sections',function($join ){
            $join->on('questions.questionid','=','sections.questionid');
        })
        ->join('options',function($join ){
            $join->on('questions.questionid','=','options.questionid');
        })
        ->where('questions.formid',$formId)
        ->get();
```

Comment: it returns nothing @Kaleem Shoukat

Comment: It's important that the query returns me questions records where questions.formid = $formId whether matched records exist in sections or options tables  @Kaleem Shoukat